# How can I resolve these warnings?

Tags: github, warnings

I'm given these warnings on GitHub and I am wondering how to fix them. It is not overwhelmingly clear!

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is below.

- Remove all the lock files and node modules
- Then do a `npm i` which will generate lock files with updated packages.

This should fix at least some of your warnings. Sometimes, it might fix all.